# Use Javascript code inside a xsl document

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt, transformation

I would to use Javascript code inside a xsl file to generate a dinamic HTML page.
I tried some solutions like use CDATA inside the script tag but none of these worked.
The XML file is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<gruppo>
    <nome>Casa Miles</nome>
    <studente>
        <id>sergio</id>
        <nome>sergio</nome>
        <cognome>zavota</cognome>
        <scontrino>
            <prodotto>
                <nome>sapone piatti</nome>
                <quantità>1</quantità>
                <costo>3.3</costo>
                <partecipante>
                    <id>stefano</id>
                </partecipante>
                <partecipante>
                    <id>sergio</id>
                </partecipante>
            </prodotto>
            <prodotto>
                <nome>bresaola</nome>
                <quantità>1</quantità>
                <costo>5.5</costo>
                <partecipante>
                    <id>sergio</id>
                </partecipante>
            </prodotto>
            <prodotto>
                <nome>pasta</nome>
                <quantità>10</quantità>
                <costo>0.5</costo>
                <partecipante>
                    <id>stefano</id>
                </partecipante>
                <partecipante>
                    <id>sergio</id>
                </partecipante>
            </prodotto>
            <prodotto>
                <nome>pane</nome>
                <quantità>3</quantità>
                <costo>1.4</costo>
                <partecipante>
                    <id>stefano</id>
                </partecipante>
                <partecipante>
                    <id>sergio</id>
                </partecipante>
            </prodotto>
            <data>2020-02-10</data>
            <pagato>true</pagato>
        </scontrino>
        <pagamenti>
            <partecipante>
                <id>Stefano</id>
                <quota>-33.0</quota>
            </partecipante>
        </pagamenti>
    </studente>
    <studente>
        <id>stefano</id>
        <nome>stefano</nome>
        <cognome>Silvestri</cognome>
        <scontrino>
            <prodotto>
                <nome>shampoo</nome>
                <quantità>2</quantità>
                <costo>2.3</costo>
                <partecipante>
                    <id>stefano</id>
                </partecipante>
            </prodotto>
            <prodotto>
                <nome>insalata</nome>
                <quantità>4</quantità>
                <costo>0.5</costo>
                <partecipante>
                    <id>stefano</id>
                </partecipante>
                <partecipante>
                    <id>sergio</id>
                </partecipante>
            </prodotto>
            <prodotto>
                <nome>hamburger</nome>
                <quantità>1</quantità>
                <costo>3.6</costo>
                <partecipante>
                    <id>stefano</id>
                </partecipante>
            </prodotto>
            <prodotto>
                <nome>pane</nome>
                <quantità>3</quantità>
                <costo>1.4</costo>
                <partecipante>
                    <id>stefano</id>
                </partecipante>
                <partecipante>
                    <id>sergio</id>
                </partecipante>
            </prodotto>
            <data>2020-03-10</data>
            <pagato>true</pagato>
        </scontrino>
        <pagamenti>
            <partecipante>
                <id>Sergio</id>
                <quota>33.0</quota>
            </partecipante>
        </pagamenti>
    </studente>
</gruppo>
```

The xsl file is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
    <xsl:strip-space elements="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="tableByDataScontrino" match="scontrino" use="data" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>HTML Document</title>

            </head>

            <style>
                table {
                font-family: arial, sans-serif;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                width: 100%;
                }

                td, th {
                border: 1px solid #dddddd;
                text-align: left;
                padding: 8px;
                }

                tr:nth-child(even) {
                background-color: #dddddd;
                }   

                caption {
                display: table-caption;
                text-align: center;
                }

            </style>

            <body>

                <h2 align="center">Benvenuto <xsl:value-of select="gruppo/studente[nome='sergio']/nome"/></h2>
                <h2 align="center">Gruppo: <xsl:value-of select="gruppo/nome"/> </h2>
                <h2 align="center">Scontrini</h2>

                <xsl:for-each select="gruppo/studente/scontrino[generate-id() = generate-id(key('tableByDataScontrino',data)[1])]">
                    <table>
                        <caption style="font-weight: bold;">Data: <xsl:value-of select="data"/></caption>

                        <tr>
                            <th>Nome</th> 
                            <th>Quantità</th>
                            <th>Costo</th>
                            <th>Totale</th>
                            <th>Partecipanti</th>       
                        </tr>
                        <xsl:for-each select="key('tableByDataScontrino',data)/prodotto">
                            <xsl:sort select="data" /> 
                            <tr>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="nome"/></td>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="quantità"/></td>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="costo"/></td>
                                <td>Calcolato tramite Javascript</td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="partecipante">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </td>     
                            </tr>

                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </table>
                </xsl:for-each>

                <h2 align="center" id="dataOdierna"></h2>

                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Studente</th>
                        <th>Quota</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="gruppo/studente[nome='sergio']/pagamenti/partecipante/id"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="gruppo/studente[nome='sergio']/pagamenti/partecipante/quota"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <script>
                    currentDate = (new Date()).toLocaleDateString('en-GB');
                    document.getElementById("dataOdierna").innerHTML = "Pagamenti alla data: " + currentDate;                   
                </script>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that i tried to insert a script inside the body, but when i use a XSLT processor, the script isn't parsed correctly.

Comment: XSLT processors do not have any comprehension of JavaScript code. So, due to that, they don't parse it at all. It's just text content to them. Luckily (and probably accidentally) you do not have any [predefined XML entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML) in your JavaScript code (like `<` or `&` and so on), because in this case you would have gotten one or more errors.

Comment: Script inside an HTML document, whether the HTML document is a static one or the result of an XSLT transformation, might be executed by a browser. It is not clear in which context you use XSLT and when you expect the script to be executed. If you feed the result of your stylesheet to a browser, like done in the `HTML` result view of https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmC4HK, you will see that the browser executes the script.

Comment: I understood the problem. Could i import a javascript file in the xsl file?